How to pass a value or props to a css style file
I need to update the x and y position where a user clicks to populate the top and left properties of a div:
.dataCardAbsolute {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
}

  React.useEffect(() => {
    document.body.addEventListener('click', (event) => { setPosition([event.pageX, event.pageY]) })
  }, []);

  <div
  className={{styles.`dataCardAbsolute-${}`}} //an attempt...
  className={styles.dataCardAbsolute}         
 >


How do I pass the updated position to the css file?

I'm assuming the state for the setter function is position so is the code to update it, you would have to update it via inline styles, this would be the easiest route.
 <div
      className={styles.dataCardAbsolute}
      style={{ top: `${position.top}px`, left: `${position.left}px` }}
    >


You can try using CSS variables (like the ones you usually set in your :root declaration).
With CSS variables you can even set "default" variables by writing them statically in the "style" attribute of your div.
Here's a little example ;) !


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  let button = document.getElementById("buttonID");
  let item = document.getElementById("itemID");
   
   let toggle = false;

  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    item.style = toggle ? "--radius: 50%;" : "--radius: 20%;";
    toggle = !toggle;
  });
});
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.button {
  background-color: aliceblue;
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
}

.item {
  border-radius: var(--radius);
  
  background-color: green;
  width: 30%;
  height: 40%;
}
<button class="button" id="buttonID">Resize the item</button>
<div class="item" id="itemID" style="--radius: 50%;"></div>




Now you can just adapt this to your top and left properties and here you go !
